# Akka/scala-OversizedPayloadException How to handel it?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka-http, akka-cluster

We have a distributed application on akka cluster. Actor “A” sends message of large size to a remote actor. And we get the following warning:

> 2016-08-10 23:08:29,737 [EndpointWriter] ERROR - Transient association
>   error (association remains live)
>   akka.remote.OversizedPayloadException: Discarding oversized payload
>   sent to Actor[akka.tcp://abcd@127.0.0.1:51665/temp/$b]: max allowed
>   size 128000 bytes, actual size of encoded class
>   common.data.model.configuration.UserList was 571444 bytes.

We are aware that we can increase the value in the [configuration](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/scala/remoting.html#Remote_Configuration). But we wanted to check if the size exceeds the default limit we want to send a different message. Tried searching but no luck most of them only tell on how to configure it no one talks about on how to handle it and send the remote machine a message. Any suggestion or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, we are able to handle it, just need to subscribe for `akka.event.Logging.Error`, and check, if the cause is `OversizedPayloadException`:

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, Props}

class Listener extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case akka.event.Logging.Error(cause, _, _, _)
      // this internal Akka class is package-private, hence we have to check it's classname :(
      if cause.getClass.getName == "akka.remote.OversizedPayloadException" =>
      // handle it here!
  }
}

val listener = system.actorOf(Props(new Listener))
system.eventStream.subscribe(listener, classOf[akka.event.Logging.Error])
```

Comment: fantastic... Will try to make use of it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Posted the same query to Akka mailing group. They said like there is no option of handeling this "OversizedPayloadException". Thy suggest that we should check the data size and handel it before we return to the actor.

Comment: I am trying to check the json size I am sending as a part of clustermessage but then, in a border case where my message size is very close to the limit set(but still less), it throws an error saying that it is encoding the message further and increasing its size because of some encoding. Can you help me how to get the size of the encoded message that is being sent over?

Answer (score 0):

Try to subscribe to the event stream. Hopefully that exception will end there:

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, Props}
import akka.remote.OversizedPayloadException

class Listener extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case d: OversizedPayloadException  => {
        // DO SOMETHING
    }
  }
}
val listener = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[Listener], this))
system.eventStream.subscribe(listener, classOf[OversizedPayloadException])
```

More info [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.10/scala/event-bus.html#Event_Stream)

Comment: When I try to do the above I get error "class OversizedPayloadException in package remote cannot be accessed in package akka.remote". I am sure that I am doing some basic mistake. Can you please guide me.

Comment: Any reason why i am getting this exception?

Comment: @Prakash you can't access it, because `OversizedPayloadException` is private inside akka.remote package.

p.s. I know, that it's probably too late for you, but for others maybe not... :)

Comment: @EvgenyVeretennikov yes thats correct. I am aware of it now. Please refer the answer below.